# Uploading app using Application loader give error

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am trying to uploading my application on apple store using `Application Loader. My application is support from`iOS-8` on words. While uploaing I got the error Which I have mentioned using a screen shot.
Error is about

### ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'."

**Application Loader error**

[image]

I have used 'Images.xcassets' for `launch image`. So there is no any option for the `image who have {320,568}`. so what to do I didn't understand. I have attached that screen shot as well.

**Image.xcassets screenshot**
[image]

If anyone has any idea on it, please help me.

Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: can you show your info plist file and check the every launch image size

Comment: @Tj3n I have tried, but not working.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P in info plist file launch image size is not available.

Comment: It seems like its the iOS 6 and prior stuff, but u might need the exact resolution, not using same image for everything